# How can I keep track of odata transactions ?

Tags: odata

I need to know how many requests I received through odata protocol. Is there any way I can keep track of this ? I need it for analytics purpose. (using a custom tool is not allowed, but nevertheless it could be great if you can point me to some).

Thanks, Ritwik

Comment: Does WCF Performance Counters fit into your requirements?

Comment: are there any counters specifically for odata ?I am not aware .. please tell me which ones can be used for odata transactions

Comment: If you are exposing OData via WCF Data Services then you could use operation performance counters (calls, calls x second, transactions...) check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731052.aspx

Comment: I'd also suggest looking at the options for IIS logging. IIS logs are pretty straightforward and it's easy to sort out the OData URLs.

Comment: @MarkStafford-MSFT that really helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few options you could consider:

If you need to capture the data into your own custom format/DB hook into the WCF Data Services ProcessingPipeline (there are general events there for pre and post processing queries and data change events) - [CodeProject Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190202/WCF-Data-Services-Processing-Pipeline)

If you need your own format but for specific entities, check out the Query and Change Interceptors - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744842.aspx)

If you can use another framework and need a quick, ready to go dashboard (built into IIS) check out AppFabric Monitoring (requires some install/setup on the server) [WCF Data Service and AppFabric](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/06/30/appfabric-wcf-data-service-cs.aspx)